# Sefer haKabbalah: How long did Jehoshaphat reign?

Tags: history, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, contradiction

In the book of [Melachim Alef 22:42](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a22.htm#42) it says:

> Jehoshaphat was thirty and five years old when he began to reign; and
>   he reigned **twenty and five years** in Jerusalem.

Seder Olam (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.17.2?lang=bi)) agrees with that:

> בשנת שלשים ושמנה שנה לאסא מלך יהודה (מלך) [וימלך] אחאב בן עמרי על
>   ישראל [בשמרון] עשרים ושתים שנה (שם טז כט), בשנת ארבע לאחאב מלך יהושפט,
>   בן ל"ה שנה היה במלכו, **כ"ה שנה מלך בירושלם**

But looking at [Sefer haKabbalah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Qabbalah) it seems that it does have some 'inconsistences' (perhaps, due to typo?). Compare for instance, [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/ravad/ravad01.pdf) it says 28 years and also [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52628&st=&pgnum=62), but [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46767&st=&pgnum=119&hilite=) it says 21 and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34252&st=&pgnum=33) 95. Am I missing something? Which one is correct? 
 And if is one of these, which differs from SO and the posuk above, what source and reasoning supports it?

Comment: Can you please translate some of the links for the "inconsistencies" into English so more of us could understand what this question is asking about? Thanks!

Comment: In general would be ideal if the question could be self standing and not require the reader to open links to understand the question

Comment: @Gary, clarification added.